# Disable Print Screen on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know it does not make any sense to disable the print screen in web page. If you want it, you can use any third party tools, but however I have to implement it. I'm Trying following code:
https://codepen.io/sartaj-husain/pen/NYRKGQ
 in my web page. 
The code only works, when the page gets load & I click somewhere in the web page. I want to run it when page gets load itself.

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
        if (keyCode == 44) {
            stopPrntScr();
        }
    });
    function stopPrntScr() {

        var inpFld = document.createElement("input");
        inpFld.setAttribute("value", ".");
        inpFld.setAttribute("width", "0");
        inpFld.style.height = "0px";
        inpFld.style.width = "0px";
        inpFld.style.border = "0px";
        document.body.appendChild(inpFld);
        inpFld.select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
        inpFld.remove(inpFld);
    }
   function AccessClipboardData() {
        try {
            window.clipboardData.setData('text', "Access   Restricted");
        } catch (err) {
        }
    }
    setInterval("AccessClipboardData()", 300);

    });
```

Comment: "I want to run it when page gets load itself" what?

Comment: the code works when i click somewhere in the web page. If i press 'print screen' when page gets loads, without clicking somewhere, code fails.

Comment: So instead of saving the screen-image to clipboard you save something else? and you want it to work before domContentLoaded?

Comment: Code which was provided with the link actually does not work properly

Comment: Why not listen for `window.onload` instead of `keyup` ?

Comment: You can't catch `keypress` event when user is not focused on you page

Comment: @A.Meshu right, is it possible?

Comment: It sounds impossible. BUT you can make some fake-loader and then trigger your function... And also @MarkMinerov comment (:

Comment: Also `window.clipboardData` is IE only.  But really, changing the user's clipboard when they're not even in your window... bit rude?